# How to remove subarray in multidimensional array if exsits the same values in other array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two multidimensional arrays:

```
Array A
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reservation_start] => 08:00:00
            [reservation_end] => 08:35:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [reservation_start] => 08:35:00
            [reservation_end] => 09:10:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [reservation_start] => 09:10:00
            [reservation_end] => 09:45:00
        )
)

Array B
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reservation_start] => 08:00:00
            [reservation_end] => 08:35:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [reservation_start] => 08:35:00
            [reservation_end] => 09:10:00
        )

)
```

foreach loop:

```
foreach ($allHours as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $busyHours)) {
        unset($allHours[$key]);
    }
}
```

And now I would like to remove from array A values exists in array.
I used  unset in foreach, but in each time arrays have different size so it does not work.

EDIT:
Found a problem, it was in my DB, return wrong time. Thank you for help

Comment: Can you share your foreach loop

Comment: Did you try array_diff ?

Comment: _"I used unset in foreach, but in each time arrays have different size so it does not work"._ Can you clarify that? Right now your code seems to give expected results - https://3v4l.org/WJTYo

Comment: I found an error. It was in SQL, return wrong hours like 08:00:35 (mistake of seconds and minutes)

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = [
    [ 'start' => '08:00:00', 'end' => '08:35:00' ],
    [ 'start' => '08:35:00', 'end' => '09:10:00' ],
    [ 'start' => '09:10:00', 'end' => '09:45:00' ]
];

$array2 = [
    [ 'start' => '08:00:00', 'end' => '08:35:00' ],
    [ 'start' => '08:35:00', 'end' => '09:10:00' ]
];

$result = [];

array_walk($array1, function ($value1) use (&$result, $array2) {
  if(!array_filter($array2, fn($item2) => $value1 == $item2)) {
    $result[] = $value1;
  }
});
```

Comment: it should return an item that differs like [ 'start' => '09:10:00', 'end' => '09:45:00' ]

Comment: Just mad the necessary changes to the code.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is also good.

Answer (score 1):

assuming arrays `A = allhours` `B = busyhours`

- stringfy both & reduce to 1-dimensional array

```
    foreach ($all as $k=>$arr) {
        $all_copy[$k] = $arr['reservation_start'] . $arr['reservation_end'];
    }

    foreach ($busy as $k=>$arr) {
        $busy_copy[$k] = $arr['reservation_start'] . $arr['reservation_end'];
    }
```

- take [array difference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) (if exist in busy, then remove it from all)

```
    // array_diff preserves keys.
    $non_busy = array_diff($all_copy, $busy_copy);
```

- get resultant array from the original `all`

```
foreach ($non_busy as $k=>$no_need)
{
   $result[$k] = $all[$k];
}
```

- you may unset arrays that you won't need anymore except `$result`